# Compare tables and Find the missing records

Tags: sql

I am trying to compare a table **T1** and a view **v1** and find the missing records from the table T1 and display the results in a excel when a button is clicked. I am trying the wrap up the situation into a stored procedure and call it from vba code.  I am not sure on how to start this.. The field names are different in both the tables, although it has same data.  Any help will be much appreciated. I have tried many code samples , but I didn't achieve what I want..

**Table T1**

alpha.FileID

Master Policy Number

Insurance Name

**View V1**

FileID

PolNO

InsName

These are the few columns. Though, they have different field names, the data are the same. Some times the records are missing in the table **v1,** and I need to compare the two tables and find the missing records of the table v2.

```
           SELECT View_v1.[Insured Name] 

            FROM   View_v1

            WHERE   View_v1.alpha.FileID NOT IN      

            (        

                   SELECT Table_t1.FileID   

                   FROM    Table_t1       

            )
```

Comment: Please provide the tables, sample data and code that you've tried.

Comment: I would recommend that that you at least provide the Table and view schema. and some code that you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: This is probably not very hard to do. But you'll need to describe what kinds of differences you're looking for and how you picture this being displayed.. Do you have key columns to match up on? Are you looking for differences in individual columns?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158569/how-to-check-for-record-which-has-no-entry-in-another-table-with-some-specific-v/158575?noredirect=1#comment304209_158575

Comment: I have included the code that I tried

Answer (score 0):

An except clause is the easiest way to do this:

```
SELECT FileID, PolNO, InsName
  FROM View V1
EXCEPT
SELECT FileID, MasterPolicyNumber, InsuranceName
  FROM Table T1
```

This will give you the rows in the first select that do not exist in the second select (depending on your desired results you might flip the top and bottom selects). As long as the data types and number of columns are the same, the name of each field doesn't matter.  Your result set will show the field names of the first select.

Also since you didn't specify your dbms, "MINUS" is used instead of "EXCEPT" for some dbms's like Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for based on your description.

I'm comparing every field, not just FileID as your example appears to be attempting. So, if you truly want to look only for missing FileIDs, just remove the other join on conditions.

```
SELECT View_v1.FileID, View_v1.PolNO, View_v1.InsName 
FROM   View_v1
LEFT JOIN Table_t1 
    on View_v1.FileID = Table_t1.FileID 
    and View_v1.PolNO = Table_t1.[Master Policy Number] 
    and View_v1.InsName = Table_t1.[Insurance Name]
WHERE   Table_t1.FileID is null
```